# System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary error using SSJS HttpRequest

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I am trying to complete a DELETE request using SSJS on a landing page, using API mocking tools (beeceptor.com) I'm able to fake the API calls to see how the page reacts.

Calling the DELETE request, the resource will either return a 204 or a 404 response code, and nothing in the body.

When a 204 is returned the cost works without issues, when a 404 is returned I get the following error:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

Here is my code:

```
<script runat=server language="javascript">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");

    var DELETE_URL  = "https://delete-api.free.beeceptor.com";

    try {
        var payload = {};
        payload.url = 'http://site.com/image.jpg';
        var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(DELETE_URL);
        req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
        req.retries = 2;
        req.continueOnError = false;
        req.contentType = "application/json";
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'App api-key-goes-here');
        req.postData = Stringify(payload);

        req.method = "DELETE";
        var resp = req.send();
        Write(resp);

    } catch (e) {
        Write(e);
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 404 is an error and frequently returns no response payload. Set emptyContentHandling and continueOnError to true and then inspect the response using its statusCode, returnStatus, errorMessage and content properties.